# Why React fire events in different order when simulating mobile devices in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, dom-events

Consider the following text input and a checkbox:

[image]

```
<div>
  <div className="field">
    <label htmlFor="name">Name: </label>
    <input
      id="name"
      type="text"
      onBlur={() => {
        console.log("onBlur");
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("onBlur next tick");
        });
      }}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="field">
    <input
      id="toggle"
      type="checkbox"
      onChange={() => {
        console.log("onChange");
      }}
    />
    <label htmlFor="toggle">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

User does the following:

1. Focuses on the Name input
2. Clicks/taps the toggle

In Chrome, the order of the `console.log`s is:

```
onBlur 
onBlur next tick 
onChange
```

But, when [simulating mobile devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode), the order changes to:

```
onBlur 
onChange
onBlur next tick
```

Interestingly, in Firefox the order doesn't change when simulating mobile devices.

Why is this order change happening in Chrome? Is this documented somewhere?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-sun-qlcim?file=/src/App.js)

---

**UPDATE:**

I just recreated the same example in pure JavaScript, and the result is the same: https://jsbin.com/vagoloxebi/edit?html,js,output

This means that React is not the issue here.

Is this a bug in Chrome?

Comment: It's certainly Chrome-specific behavior, labeling it a bug if would depend on who you ask. I'd be very surprised if SO provides you a suitable answer to this question. I imagine your best shot comes from reporting an issue on [chromium browser](https://www.chromium.org/Home)

Comment: @Adam Thanks, done. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1164788